# Scope are not updated AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sad... I cook porridge of the ax..
Please, if you can - help me deal with my problem.
I have this structure in my html code(ng-controller is on wrap tag):

```
<a ng-repeat="subitem in cur_submenu" ng-href="#/{{subitem.href}}/">{{subitem.name}}</a>
```

In JS I have:
1) RouteProvider

```
$routeProvider.
      when('/:lvl1', {
          template:'<div ng-include="htmlUrl">Loading...</div>',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
```

2) Controller

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams){
  var lvl = window.location.hash.split('/');
  if ($scope.submenu) {
    //if data was fetch earlier, then set currentMenu
    $scope.cur_submenu = $scope.submenu[lvl[1]];
  } else {
    MainCtrl.prototype.fetchData();
  }

  MainCtrl.prototype = {
    fetchData: function(){
      /*
      * Get data about navigation
      */
      $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data/main.json'}).
      success(function(data){
        $scope.menu = data.menu;
        $scope.submenu = data.submenu;
        $scope.cur_submenu = data.submenu[lvl[1]] //current submenu for my location
      });
   }
}
```

But it is not updating on my page, when I changed my location on a website(hash-nav)... Please help my. Full version of my site: http://amiu.ru

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a function to your Controller with prototyping. Functions called in your view are to be declared on the $scope like so:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams){
  var lvl = window.location.hash.split('/');
  if ($scope.submenu) {
    //if data was fetch earlier, then set currentMenu
    $scope.cur_submenu = $scope.submenu[lvl[1]];
  } else {
    $scope.fetchData();
  }

  $scope.fetchData = function(){
      /*
      * Get data about navigation
      */
      $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data/main.json'}).
          success(function(data){
            $scope.menu = data.menu;
            $scope.submenu = data.submenu;
            $scope.cur_submenu = data.submenu[lvl[1]] //current submenu for my location
          });
   };
}
```

In all other cases, if you're executing changes on a $scope outside of a $scope function, you'll need to manually call `$scope.$apply()` to queue a digest and update your view.